# How can I change Delphi's cursor shape when it's in overwrite mode?

Tags: delphi

When using Delphi, any version, I sometimes happen to hit the insert key and turn on overwrite mode. This is often a great nuisance and the only indication you have entered overwrite mode is the small text at the bottom of the editor.

When using other programs (first to come to mind is Notepad++) when you are in insert mode the text cursor is `|` and when you are in overwrite mode the cursor changes to `_`

Is there an option somewhere or a way to have Delphi use a different text cursor when in overwrite mode?

Comment: The other indication that you're in overwrite mode, is that stuff starts overwriting.  I think we all just get used to it, see it, ctrl+Z to undo, tap Insert, and go on.

Comment: Yes I have come to know that routine all too well.

Comment: But overwrite mode can be very useful sometimes.

Comment: Agreed, I do make use of it at times, its just the accidental times that annoy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, the 'normal' behaviour is that the caret is a thin vertical line in insert mode, and a thick (1 character wide) block in overwrite mode.

Apparently, the IDE doesn't support this. But it does support '[BRIEF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brief_(text_editor)) cursor shapes'. They probably mean 'Brief *caret* shapes', but we still understand what they mean, right? ;)

Using this option, the insert caret is a thin *horizontal* line (uncommon!), and the overwrite caret is the normal thick block that we are all used to (common).

[image: Delphi 2009 IDE options]

Comment: Also known as "DOS program edit cursors", if you remember that far back.

Comment: @Ken: Well, but I am pretty sure that the official Win32 terminology makes a very clear distinction between [cursors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646970(VS.85).aspx) and [carets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646968(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Yes, but Brief was a DOS editor published by Borland pre-Windows, so "Brief cursor shapes" relates to before "official Win32 terminology". :)

Comment: The thin horizontal line was very common in DOS character mode applications, and it was called a cursor back then.  DOS character mode applications typically didn't use the mouse at all.

Comment: i do not see this option in D7

Comment: I always use the BRIEF cursor shapes :) Since Pascal times.