# What is "Show image on tabs"?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I am in a spree to configure my IDE. Many things are explained in the good-old-Borland-help style.

For example under "Editor->Display" one can find a new feature called "Show image on tabs". And the Help page for it:

> "Displays an icon on each tab in the Code Editor".

Oh... the glory of the Help page!

So, does anyone knows what this means? If I enable/disable it, I see no changes in my editor's look.

Comment: There's some mismatch between the title and the body of this question. I assume the body is correct.

Comment: I assume the OP already knows what BRIEF editor cursor shapes is, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5782392/576719

Comment: Fixed the title. This is because yet another bug in the Help. I wanted to copy the "Show image on tabs" but the Ctrl+C won't work there. To copy text from the Help you need to right click on the selected text then choose "copy'. So many times I pasted whatever was previously in the clipboard because of this bug. Well... at least we can blame MS for this bug :)

Comment: @InTheNameOfScience: Please don't blame Microsoft for Embarcadero's bugs. :) Microsoft's HTML help viewer certainly supports Ctrl+C to copy the current selection. Just try it in some other CHM file on your system (WinMerge, 7-zip, ...). The problem is that the RAD Studio IDE has a *global* Ctrl+C handler (maybe a `TAction`) which steals it from the currently focused control. Similarly for cut and paste. You will notice that Ctrl+C won't work in many edit fields in the IDE. Another example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59929759/282848

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - SORRY! I thought that since it happens in the MS Help program it is a Microsoft problem. I never thought about a possible "stolen" Ctrl+C shortcut.

Comment: Another bug is that as long as the "Options" window is open in the IDE, the Help program cannot be accessed/does not respond to mouse/keyboard events. Looks like "Options" is set modal not only over the IDE but also over Help. So, in order to read the Help page for "Tools->Options" you need to close the "Options" window. Great :)

Comment: @InTheNameOfScience When you open Help documentation in Delphi it is opened in a window that belongs to Delphi and not as standalone application. This is why modal Options dialog prevents you from interacting with help window. So this isn't actually a bug but instead a poor design.

Comment: @SilverWarior - I would call it a bug :) If a "poor design" is so poor that the program cannot be used anymore... then that's a bug. I wonder if anyone Emba ever tried to their own open the Help page.... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this in Delphi 2009.

In Delphi 2009, this setting controls the display of icons on the IDE's main tabs (IDE restart required for the change to take effect):

[image: Screenshot of editor with tab images]

[image: Screenshot of editor without tab images]

Modern Delphi versions don't have such icons, as far as I know, so it seems like this setting no longer has any effect.